# How to update/change schemaExtension owner app

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to update schemaExtension owner?

E.g. when someone deletes the app that created schemaExtension and schemaExtension is orphaned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/schemaextension):

> The `appId` of the application that is the owner of the schema extension. This property can be supplied on creation, to set the owner.  If not supplied, then the calling application's `appId` will be set as the owner. In either case, the signed-in user must be the owner of the application. **Once set, this property is read-only and cannot be changed**.